# What's a good general mechanism for referencing ID's in a routed Single Page Application?

Tags: javascript, dom, single-page-application

Many SPAs seem to use the hash `#` to indicate the beginning of the SPA's routing. All good so far, but when I have a `<div id=xyz>` and I want to refer to `href="#xyz"`, this no longer works, since I now have a URL that would look something like `myapp.com#/some/spa/page#xyz`, and it seems the browser doesn't know how to deal with nested hashes/pound signs.

Is there a general mechanism that can still leverage ids, or do we have to use javascript at this point to somehow scroll to a particular `div` on the page?

Comment: I don’t really see single-page applications use `#` very often. Usually, you’d have `https://myapp.com/some/spa/page#xyz` where `/some/spa/page` is a path that can be set with the History API.

Comment: This *might* help, though it's about React:  https://medium.com/@gajus/making-the-anchor-links-work-in-spa-applications-618ba2c6954a

Comment: Thanks @Amy - `scrollIntoView` looks useful, I'll try some of this out tomorrow.